# Text Resize jQuery Plugin with Ipad, Iphone and other Mobile Device Support

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need `Text Resize` Option for my Web Site which should work in all the browsers and Mobile Devices.

so any one suggest jQuery plugin or any other library to implement this functionality

- Mozilla Firefox
- Google Chrome
- Internet Explorer 8
- Other devices like IPAD, IPHONE, Android Mobiles and Windows Mobiles

### I need maximum 3 level bigger and 3 level smaller

Comment: EASIEST way, and i've done this on an application that is now used on PC's, Tablets, and Mobile Devices. Give a font size to your `BODY`. Throughout the rest of the sight, everything within body, (it does take some work if you havn't started it this way), use `em` anytime you need a font-size change. Then make a tool (on my application it's in a top hand menu, in a slider) where the user can adjust font-size. I simply have it adjust the `BODY { font-size: XXpx; }`. It's cross-browser/cross-platform and has worked very well for the client I made it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download test both works g8
    https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill
    https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Comment: Thanks for a nice search! on this plugins

Answer (score 1):

There is [JQuery.InputFit](https://github.com/vxsx/jquery.inputfit.js)  plugin, you can use like this:

```
<input type="text" name="younameit" id="input">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').inputfit();
</script>
```

Alternatively you could use JS to make your own:

```
<p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the characters size.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">


function myFunction(){
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
    var initialSize=25-x.value.length;
    initialSize=initialSize<=10?10:initialSize;
x.style.fontSize = initialSize + "px";
}
```

and maybe fix the input size:

```
#fname {
    height:25px;
    width:225px;
}
```

check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/A8bap/)

As for resizing the whole body, you can do somethng like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myOriginalMonitorWidth=1500;
   var thisWidth= $('body').width();
   var reFactor = thisWidth/myOriginalMonitorWidth;
   var ActualSize=  $('body').css("font-size");
        ActualSize = ActualSize.replace('px','');
    var NewSize=  parseInt( (ActualSize*reFactor),10);
     $('body').css("font-size",NewSize+"px");


});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/bJPJM/) .

Comment: question is about text re-size of whole site

Answer (score 0):

You can use below jquery plugin for that.

http://demos.angstrey.com/jquery/plugins/jquery.textresizer/demos/simple-demo.htm